# C++: use of undeclared identifier 'u8'

Tags: c++, utf-8

```
const char* hi = "hi"; // ok
const char* hi2 = u8"hi"; // compile error
```

It causes

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'u8'

My compiler supports `C++ 11`.

```
~/Project/cpp  c++ -v
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0 
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 10):

Your compiler doesn't default to C++11 though.

```
[9:46pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] c++ -c blah.cc
blah.cc:2:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'u8'
const char* hi2 = u8"hi"; // compile error
                  ^
blah.cc:2:21: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
const char* hi2 = u8"hi"; // compile error
                    ^
                    ;
2 errors generated.
[9:47pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] c++ -c -std=c++11 blah.cc
[9:47pm][wlynch@watermelon /tmp]
```